# How to compute $\mathbb{E}_X \log(1+\exp(X))$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

### Problem

> **Obtain**:  $\mathbb{E}_X \log(1+\exp(X))$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

---

### Definitions

- Logistic function: $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(x) := \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$
- Logit function: $\displaystyle \mathcal{L}^{-1}(y) := \log \left( \frac{y}{1-y} \right)$

---

### Try

First let $\displaystyle Y\equiv -\log \left( \frac{1}{1+\exp(X)} \right) = -\log\left(\mathcal{L} (-X)\right)$. By change-of-variable,

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_Y(y) &= f_X(x) \left\vert \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right\vert\\[8pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \vert 1 + \exp(-x) \vert \\[8pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( - \frac{(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \exp(-y) \right]+\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \frac{I(y>0)}{1-\exp(-y)} \ \ \because  x = -\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \exp(-y) \right] \\[8pt]
\end{aligned}
$$

Next, let us take the expectation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}_Y[Y] &= \int_0^\infty y f_Y(y) dy \\[8pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{y}{1-\exp(-y)} \exp\left( - \frac{(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \exp(-y) \right]+\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)  dy
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $w:=-\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ \exp(-y) \right]$, then

$$
dw = \exp(-y) \left( \frac{1}{\exp(-y)} + \frac{1}{1-\exp(-y)} \right) dy = \frac{dy}{1-\exp(-y)} 
$$

which circularly begs the original question as

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}_Y[Y] &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(1+\exp(w)) \exp \left( -\frac{(w-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dw \\[8pt]
&= \mathbb{E}_X \log(1+\exp(X))
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get the exact solution... If you just want an approximate value , there is an approximation for $1+Y$, where $Y$ follows a lognormal distribution.

Comment: @Babado Can you be more specific? Currently I could not relate my question to lognormal distribution... Approximate value is satisfactory for me.

Comment: if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $Y=e^X \sim LogNormal(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and you can approximate $Y+1$ which follows a three parameter lognormal distribution.

Comment: @Babado Thank you I see. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) says $\mathbb{E}[1+\exp(X)] = 1 + \exp\left(\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$. So could you give any kind hints on how I should proceed with the logarithm?

Comment: A few days ago I had a problem similar to yours and I searched for an approximation of $Log(1+e^X)$ and I found something... Now I was trying to find it again but I can't find it :( . But I guess it had something to do with Taylor expansion and Monte-Carlo simulation... I'm sorry I can't help you more. However, if you have $\mu=0$, Andrew's deduction is very nice.

Comment: I don't have access to a keyboard to LaTeX this up, but [here's](https://imgur.com/pG33VqL)  a series that quickly converges to the desired value, a few terms gives a decent approximation.

Comment: @RagibZaman Looks nice to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question: [Expected Value of the Logarithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38296/expected-value-of-a-natural-logarithm) might answer your problem.

Here it states that

$$\mathbb{E}[\log(1+Y)]\approx \log(1+\mathbb{E}[Y])-\frac{\operatorname{Var}(Y)}{2(1+\mathbb{E}[Y])^2}$$
In our case, since $Y = e^X \sim \operatorname{LogNormal(}\mu,\sigma^2)$, we get that
$$\mathbb{E}[\log(1+e^X)] \approx \log(1+e^{\mu+\frac12 \sigma^2})-\frac{(e^{\sigma^2}-1)e^{2 \mu + \sigma^2}}{2(1+e^{\mu+\frac12 \sigma^2})^2}$$